# Post mutation with child array of objects

Tags: graphql, apollo, prisma

I've read every other SO/Hackernoon/Graph.cool post about this I can find, but it's still completely eluding me.

Say I have a type called `Person`, with a relation of `Dependant`:

```
type Person {
  id: ID! @unique
  createdAt: DateTime!
  updatedAt: DateTime!
  firstName: String
  middleName: String
  lastName: String
  dependants: [Dependant!]!
}
```

I just, absolutely cannot post a `Person` object with its children and have the server not die on me. The logical way doesn't work, because nothing in life is that easy:

```
mutation CREATE_PERSON (
    $firstName: String,
    $middleName: String,
    $lastName: String,
    $dependants: [Dependant!]!,
)

returns "Variable "$dependants" cannot be non-input type "[Dependant!]!"
```

I've been told to concatenate the original type, related field and related type into "PersondependantsDependant":

```
mutation CREATE_PERSON (
    $firstName: String,
    $middleName: String,
    $lastName: String,
    $dependants: [PersondependantsDependant!]!,
)

return "Unknown type "PersondependantsDependant"
```

but that obviously doesn't work, and isn't shown in the playground or anything. Others have said it's not possible and to just JSON-encode it into a string and decode.

Is there an actual solution out there? This really isn't a nightmare in every other language.

Answer (score 0):

The Dependent type must be an "input" type, perhaps you set it up as a "type"? Add this to your schema and it should work:

```
// This will work:
input Dependent {
  someField: string!
}

// This will _NOT_ work:
type Dependent {
  someField: string!
}
```

It also seems your mutation query is incomplete. It currently only takes the  input params, but the mutation query is not there... It should look something like this:

```
mutation CREATE_PERSON (
  $firstName: String,
  $middleName: String,
  $lastName: String,
  $dependents: [dependents!]!,
) {
  createPerson(
    firstName: $firstName
    middleName: $middleName
    lastName: $lastName
    dependents: $dependents
  ) {
    # return fields
    id
    firstName
  }
}
```

But maybe you shortened it down for brevity?